# How can I access to control in loginview (in asp.net - c#)?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, loginview

I have a loginview , that is in master page. and in login mode of login control, I have a hyperlink. I want access to hyperlink , but I get error(Object not refrence ...)

my code is :

```
HyperLink hp = FindControl("LoginView1_").FindControl("hpMng") as HyperLink;
```

Comment: Do you want to find the control from a content page?

Comment: I want access from master page to control (that is in same master page), but I can't.

Comment: then try access it by using this.Master.FindControl("LoginView1_").FindControl("hpMng") as HyperLink;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FindControl` method only searches for control that are under the collection of controls you looking for. It doesn't do a full recursive search.

And in your case, you can do something like this since you are on the same page (MasterPage)

```
        var h = this.login.FindControl("link") as HyperLink;

        this.msg.Text = h.Text;
```

Remember if the `HyperLink` control is in the `LoggedInTemplate` it will only be available when the user is **logged in**. If the `HyperLink` control is in the `AnonymousTemplate` the control will only be available when the user **has not been logged in the application**. Take this into consideration to avoid a *null reference exception*

Answer (score 1):

For me, it works fine. You are trying after login? Obviously, the control will not be render if you have declared it inside de `LoggedInTemplate` and you are not logged.

```
?FindControl("HeadLoginView").FindControl("hpMng")
{Text = "aaa"}
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink: {Text = "aaa"}
```